Using 有 or 是 to describe amount
In the sentence
今天只有24度了。(It's only 24 degrees today)
is it correct to use 是 instead of 有 to describe amount and value?
今天只是24度了。
As a general question, which one of the sentences below is grammatically correct?

客厅25平方米。(Neither 是 nor 有 is used)
客厅有25平方米。(有 is to used to describe amount)
客厅是25平方米。(是 is to used to describe amount)


In Chinese, 有 and 是 are often not interchangeable. For example, "我(只)有30元" can't be stated as "我(只)是30元", the same logic applies to your examples.
(Note: "今天是24度" is a valid response to the query - "今天是几度"?)
All of the sentences below are correct:

客厅(面积/佔地)25平方米。(Often used in verbal/commercial communication)

客厅(面积)有25平方米。(The living room has an area of 25 square meters)

客厅(面积)是25平方米。(The area of the living room is 25 square meters)



客厅25平方米。
 This is not a complete sentence.
 It is more like "客厅: 25平方米".

客厅有25平方米。
客厅 is up to 25平方米。
Like if you are a real estate sales worker or you are proudly introducing the 
apartment to someone you are buying for, you typically use this, right.

客厅是25平方米。
客厅 is 25平方米。
This is a relatively motion-less expression, just trying to be objective.


Which part you want to put emphasis on, 今天/客厅 or 24度/24平米?
If your focus is on the subject, a better choice is 是.

今天是24度。
Today is (the day with) 24 degree.
客厅是24平米。
Living room is (the room with) 24 square meters.

If you put focus is on the amount, better use 有.

今天有24度。
Today has (the temperature of) 24 degree. Today is (a day) of 24 degree.
客厅有24平米。
Living room has (the area of) 24 square meters. Living room is (a room) of 24 square meters.

To be more short, just say 今天24度/客厅24平米.
To be more complicated (and more insignificant), 今天的温度有24度/今天有24度的温度/客厅的面积有24平米/客厅有24平米的面积.
Maybe try to differ by putting them into compound sentences.

今天是24度，（今天）天气不错。
今天有24度，（24度的温度）很宜人。


客厅是24平米，（客厅）很宽敞。
客厅有24平米，（24平米的面积）足够起居使用。

